# A mapping function bindings specifies a function but does not map the following parameters:

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 database first Entity Framework 6 application that has multiple fields that are initially hidden but may be displayed depending on the role selected in a drop down.  This is for creating new administrative users of the system.

The model was created by a template and does not call for these hidden fields, I save the data with a stored procedure so that it can insert into multiple tables and not directly into a single table.

The error message I see says A mapping function bindings specifies a function NewAMSModel.Store.usp_AddAdminUser but does not map the following parameters: DivisionID, DistrictID, DepartmentID, RegionID, ZoneID, LocationID.

Here is the model as created by Visual Studio

```
namespace NewAMS.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AdminUser
    {
        public AdminUser()
        {
            this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
            this.Districts = new HashSet<District>();
            this.Divisions = new HashSet<Division>();
            this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
            this.Regions = new HashSet<Region>();
            this.Zones = new HashSet<Zone>();
        }

        public string AdminID { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte RoleID { get; set; }
        public bool ReceiveNotifications { get; set; }
        public bool ChangePW { get; set; }
        public bool Deactivated { get; set; }

        public virtual AdminLogin AdminLogin { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ALL of the properties that are listed as ICollection are foreign keys to the optional fields and should be assigned on the create page.  So I added the following properties to the model

```
public byte DivisionID { get; set; }
public byte DistrictID { get; set; }
public byte DepartmentID { get; set; }
public byte RegionID { get; set; }
public byte ZoneID { get; set; }
public byte LocationID { get; set; }
```

However, the template removes the added part every time the database is refreshed.   And when I tried to map the procedure it gives me the error message.

Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddAdminUser

@AdminID nvarchar(15),
@PersonName nvarchar(50),
@Email nvarchar(50),
@RoleID tinyint,
@ReceiveNotifications bit,
@DivisionID int = NULL,
@DistrictID int = NULL,
@DepartmentID int = NULL,
@RegionID int = NULL,
@ZoneID int = NULL,
@LocationID int = NULL

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Message varchar(100)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT PersonName FROM dbo.AdminUsers WHERE AdminID = @AdminID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT
            dbo.AdminUsers
        VALUES
        (
            @AdminID,
            @PersonName,
            @Email,
            @RoleID,
            @ReceiveNotifications,
            0,
            0
        )
        --Depending on the role assigned create the user record in the foreign key table(s)
        IF @RoleID = 4   --Division Managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.DivisionManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @DivisionID
                )    
            END
        IF @RoleID = 5   -- District Managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.DistrictManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @DistrictID
                )    
            END
        IF @RoleID = 6    -- Regional Managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.RegionManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @RegionID
                )    
            END  
        IF @RoleID = 7   -- Zone Managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.ZoneManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @ZoneID
                )    
            END
        IF @RoleID = 8   -- Department Managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.DepartmentManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @DepartmentID
                )    
            END 
        IF @RoleID = 9  -- Department Manager at a specific location
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.DepartmentManager
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @DepartmentID
                )

                INSERT 
                    dbo.Manager_Locations
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @LocationID
                )    
            END 
        IF @RoleID = 10   -- location managers
            BEGIN
                INSERT 
                    dbo.Manager_Locations
                VALUES
                (
                    @AdminID,
                    @LocationID
                )    
            END

        -- Now build the password
        DECLARE @PwdWithSalt nvarchar(60)
        DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
        DECLARE @Len int
        DECLARE @Min tinyint 
        DECLARE @Range tinyint  
        DECLARE @Exclude varchar(50)
        DECLARE @Char char
        DECLARE @Password nvarchar(20)

        SET @Len = 12
        SET @Min = 35
        SET @Range = 74
        SET @Exclude  = '0:;`0l1-<>/\[]()'''
        SET @Password = ''

        -- Create a temporary password
        WHILE @Len > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Char = char(ROUND(RAND() * @Range + @Min,0))
                IF CHARINDEX(@Char,@Exclude) = 0 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Password = @Password + @Char
                        SET @Len = @Len -1
                    END
            END
        SET @PwdWithSalt = @Password + CAST(@salt as nvarchar(36))  

        INSERT
            dbo.AdminLogins
        VALUES
        (
            @AdminID,
            HASHBYTES('SHA1',@PwdWithSalt),
            @salt
        )

        SET @Message = 'here is your temporary password ' + @Password
    END 




Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='email',
@recipients= @Email,
@subject='Your account has been created',
@body=@Message
```

Hopefully that explains what I am trying to accomplish.   I have tried creating a new model, controller and views without using a template yet that does not work. If it cannot be done in one procedure I do not mind doing it in multiple steps just need some help as to how to accomplish this the asp.net-mvc way.

Answer (score 0):

If you render them using [`@Html.Hidden`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.hidden(v=vs.111).aspx) or [`@Html.HiddenFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor(v=vs.118).aspx) for normal users then it will still post them in (but could still be edited by savvy users).

This is the same as using `<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someValue">` in raw HTML terms.

The safest thing tho is to not display the values to those who shouldn't be able to see it, remembering it in memory (e.g. [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx), a cookie). It depends on how secure you need to be.

Least secure would be to use standard html inputs within a hidden div, with `display: none` set on CSS, but that should still post back.

Comment: this is not html hidden input      it is in css with div display:none  and uses the onchange event of the drop down.    I am not worried about users doing something because this is not open to public.  It is only human resources director/manager that will have access to it and they are not going to provide access for something to someone that they do not want to have access to

Comment: That should still post back, yes.